# Underscore not showing in Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am using Dymola 2021 and 2021X, the underscore doesn't show in any models. I tried to reinstall Dymola and adjust the setting option of the text editor, but the problem still exists.
My questions are:
Is this some kind of bug in the new version?
If not a bug, how to fix this issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's the Linux version of Dymola, correct?

Comment: @MarkusA. Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start Dymola with a different font as follows (as described in the full manual on page 495, "Developing a model|Tools>options|General group settings|Base font size")

```
"C:\Program Files\Dymola 2021x\bin\Dymola.exe" –fixedfont
"Lucida Console"
```

or some other font than "Lucida Console" - I hope you have some that works; there's also plain `-font` for the non-fixed width font.

As far as I see this setting isn't stored anywhere so you will have to make a short-cut to Dymola and use that every time.

Comment: By using the following command `.\Dymola.exe -fixedfont "Lucida Console" `, the underscore shows now, but I guess I might change the default font of Windows OS.

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen this behavior before and it works just fine for all installations I have seen.
It seems you have changed some fonts, maybe on operating system level, could you change these back? Default is sans-serif for menus (see screenshot), you use a font with [serifs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serif).

[image]

Also, a line length of 50 is very questionable, the default 80 is a reasonable MINIMUM.
Can you try and reset all Dymola settings, like this:
[image]

Comment: Indeed, I installed Mactype to change the fonts of Windows system, but the problem still exists after I uninstall Mactype.

Comment: Do you see the same problem in other tools on the same computer? What happens if you copy text from Dymola and paste it into Notepad or Word?

Comment: Didn't meet this problem on other machines. When paste the text from Dymola to other software, the underscore shows normally.